# get Facebook profile page url from Facebook user id?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to construct / get the url that can take me to the profile page of a Facebook user. 
All I have is the Facebook user id, Is there a way to know what the url to his profile page is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, actually. Just navigate to http://facebook.com/[userid]. You can do this with both the user ID and username.